# VisualSVN postcommit hook

Tags: svn, hook, post-commit-hook

On my windows server machine I would like to execute a post commit hook svn update.

If i execute it on my server trough cmd it works but if I insert command into svnserver I get an error after committing from my local machine. Error is: use cleanup (and I do, I have two lines of sommand - svn cleanup and svn update), trying to write to read-only database. I am acctually just copying my directories and files form repository to a working directory of my app.

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Please show the actual script and the full error message.

Comment: In services I change account type for svn service to be local system account. now it works. My script is svn cleanup path\to\folder --username xxx --password yyy \n svn update path\to\repo path\to\folder --username xxx --password yyy